# How can I get matched utterance text from Alexa request instead of intent name?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I have created one Alexa skill which I want to communicate with my chatbot. When I am asking question to Alexa, in request only intent name is coming.But I want the utterance text also. Is it possible to get that utterance?
`"request": {
        "type": "IntentRequest",
        "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.480ebab4-cd67-418e-b67f-eb8a00b74020",
        "timestamp": "2020-02-13T06:55:52Z",
        "locale": "en-US",
        "intent": {
            "name": "ask_utterance",
            "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
        }
    }` 
This is the request.I am correctly getting intent name but i want utterance text which will then I will send to my chatbot. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't (as for now) have the complete utterance.

The only thing that is near to a complete utterance is [AMAZON.SearchQuery](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#searchquery) slot. 
Otherwise, you will obtain only slot values.